# Создать GridPanel в ExtJS

Tags: extjs

Сервер возвращает такой сложный объект. На самом деле данных внутри больше, но суть понятна, есть объекты и у них есть наследники.

```
{"data":
{"accesslist":
[{"id":1,"parentID":0,"groupName":"doctor","pointCode":"patient.view","pointName":"Patien data","pointDescription":"","children":
[{"id":2,"parentID":1,"groupName":"doctor","pointCode":"patient.personal.info","pointName":"Show patient data","pointDescription":""}]
}]
}
}
```

Мне нужно разместить этот объект в GridPanel, можете подсказать, как это сделать? Выводить в GridPanel надо pointName или pointDescription.

Я пробовал так, но это не работает.

```
var fullAccessCarribean = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
    proxy: {
        url: '/CardioService/securitymanager',
        method: 'post',
        type: 'ajax',
        extraParams:{
            mode: 'accesslist',
        },
        reader: {
            root: 'data.accesslist'
        }
    },
    root:{
        expanded: true,
    }
});


Ext.define('Ext.Modules.AdminGridForm.SettingsPanel.AccessPanel.AccessTreeGrid.AccessTreeGrid', {
    extend: 'Ext.tree.Panel',    
    alias: 'widget.accesstreegrid',

    flex: 1,

    layout: {
        type: 'hbox',
        align: 'stretch'
    },

    store: fullAccessCarribean,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Это не работает потому, что у вас отсутствует описание данных.
Оно должно выпоняться в хранилище либо через модель [Ext.data.Model](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.data.Model), либо, в случае если полей немного можно прямо в хранилище(ваш случай) в поле [fields](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.data.AbstractStore-cfg-fields):

```
Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
fields: ['pointName', 'pointDescription'],
proxy: {
    url: '/CardioService/securitymanager',
    method: 'post',
    type: 'ajax',
    extraParams:{
        mode: 'accesslist',
    },
    reader: {
        root: 'data.accesslist'
    }
},
root:{
    expanded: true,
}});
```

Также в вашем дереве отсутствует описание [колонок](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.tree.Panel-cfg-columns):

```
....
columns: [{
    text: 'pointDescription',
    dataIndex: 'pointDescription'
}, {
    text: 'pointName',
    dataIndex: 'pointName'
}]
....
```